# Raycast end position is wrong for some strange reason

Tags: unity-game-engine

As you can see from this simple code I'm casting 3 rays and red ray should be similar to magenta line it must go from startPos to endPos. But for some reason red ray is copying yellow line.

Can't understand what is wrong...

```
Vector2 startPos = transform.position;
Vector2 endPos = transform.position + transform.up * 3f;

Debug.DrawRay(Vector3.zero, startPos, Color.green);
Debug.DrawRay(Vector3.zero, endPos, Color.yellow);

Debug.DrawLine(startPos, endPos, Color.magenta);

Debug.DrawRay(startPos, endPos, Color.red);
```

[image]

Comment: your code seems correct, there is an other problem with that.

Comment: Your code isnt right.. DrawRay is not start and end, but start and direction.... get the direction between start and end as your second parameter

Answer (score 1):

According to the [doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.DrawRay.html), `Debug.DrawRay(start, dir)` draws a line from `start` to `start + dir`.

> Draws a line from start to start + dir in world coordinates.

So, `Debug.DrawRay(startPos, endPos, Color.red);` draws a line from `startPos` to `startPos + endPos`.